Dock autohide delay ONLY on hide?
I'm trying to customize dock autohide timing so that it appears quickly but also holds for a number of seconds AFTER my mouse moves off of it before the dock disappears. I've tried the following, but they only adjust the show AND hide animation delays unanimously.
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float

Autohide is a necessity for me, but I constantly move my mouse off the dock by accident while I'm in the middle of looking for something, which is beyond maddening. If there's no way to do this through terminal, does anyone know of an app that can do this?

I don't know of any app that can do this, but, as a workaround, you could use Option-Command-D to display and hide the Dock (you may have to enable it in System Setgings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Launchpad & Dock). Note that some apps (like Safari) define such a shortcut, so enabling it for the Dock will disable it for those apps.
